# How can I permanently change a network device name in CentOS8?

Tags: linux, network-interface, devices, ethernet, nmcli

I want to permanently change the **device** name of a network interface using a portable script.

The interface gets the ugly name of *enp02fghjkl1*. I want to give a pretty name of *netface1*. I have tried using `ip link` and `nmcli` and so many other things to change the **device** name permanently, and I *can* change it, but I cannot get it to persist through a reboot.

Here is the command set that works to temporarily change it:

```
sudo ip link set enp02fghjkl1 down
sudo ip link set enp02fghjkl1 name netface1
sudo nmcli connection modify Wired\ connection\ 1 con-name netface1
sudo nmcli device connect netface1
sudo nmcli con up netface1
sudo nmcli con reload
```

However, after a reboot, the command `nmcli c` shows *netface1* but the command `nmcli d` shows *enp02fghjkl1*

> Note: I have also created a network-script called *ifcfg-netface1* and placed the *uuid* in it, but it just gets ignored after a reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Step 1.
  The robust solution that worked for me:
  These four lines that must exist in the network-script file:
  **/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-somename1**

```
NAME=somename1
DEVICE=somename1
HWADDR=FE:FF:GG:11:00:10
UUID=b623cbaa-ffe2-3456-7890-1a23b465cd67
```

> Caveat: The file cannot have `HWADDR` and `MACADDR` at the same time, it can only have one or the other. You can get the `UUID` from the command `nmcli c`.

- Step 2.
  add  `net.ifnames=0` somewhere after *nomodeset* and before *rhgb* in this file:
  **/etc/default/grub**

then run the command `sudo grub2-mkconfig  -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`

- Step 3.
  Match the MAC address to the nic name in this file:
  **/etc/systemd/network/70-custom-ifnames.link**

```
[Match]
MACAddress=FE:FF:GG:11:00:10

[Link]
Name=somename1
```

- Step 4.
  Add these lines to the custom rules file:
  **/etc/udev/rules.d/70-custom-ifnames.rules**

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net",ACTION=="add",ATTR{address}=="FE:FF:GG:11:00:10",ATTR{type}=="1",NAME="somename1"
```

More details here:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/consistent-network-interface-device-naming_configuring-and-managing-networking